# Instantiate multiple prefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a ball game, So the ball pass the columns and it instantiate itself base on the columnPoolSize,

I want to intantiate multiple prefab in here. It only intantiate one prefabs base on the column size...I need to create another array for columnPrefab GameObject. However I tried to do that but it did not success...

```
public class ColumbPool : MonoBehaviour
{
  public int columnPoolSize = 5;

  public GameObject[] columns;
  public GameObject columnPrefab;
  private Vector2 objectPoolPosition = new Vector2(-15f,-25f);
  private float timeSinceLastSpawn;
  public float spawnRate = 4f;
  public float columnMin = -1f;
  public float columnMax = 3.5f;
  private float spawnXPosition = 10f;
  private int currentColumn = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        columns = new GameObject[columnPoolSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < columnPoolSize; i++)
            {
                columns[i] = (GameObject)Instantiate(columnPrefab, objectPoolPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            }
    }

    void Update()
    {
      timeSinceLastSpawn += Time.deltaTime;
      if (GameController.instance.gameOver==false && timeSinceLastSpawn>=spawnRate)
      {
          timeSinceLastSpawn = 0;
          float spawnYPosition = Random.Range(columnMin, columnMax);
          columns[currentColumn].transform.position = new Vector2(spawnXPosition,spawnYPosition);
          currentColumn++;
          if (currentColumn>=columnPoolSize)
          {
              currentColumn = 0;
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I can see you instantiate 5 columns in the Start() (if you didn't change _columnPoolSize _ in inspector) and then every 4 seconds move one of your columns into a random position. But it's not clear what do you want to achieve, please edit your question so we can understand it.

Comment: I have different prefabs.. I want to instantiate them . But in this script, I can only add one prefabs inside of the column prefab game object. I want to add all my prefabs . So i need another array to add all my prefabs and see them in the game...

Comment: create `public GameObject[] prefabs` field and populate it with all your prefabs in the inspector

Comment: I did. This time it gives an error.. "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ColumbPool.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/ColumbPool.cs:53)"  " this line of code :columns[currentColumn].transform.position = new Vector2(spawnXPosition,spawnYPosition);"  makes the problem...

Comment: IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
ColumbPool.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/ColumbPool.cs:32) and also this one gives an error. "     columns[i] = (GameObject)Instantiate(columnPrefab[i], objectPoolPosition, Quaternion.identity);"

Answer (score 0):

```
void Start()
    {
        columns = new GameObject[columnPoolSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < columnPoolSize; i++)
            {
                columns[i] = (GameObject)Instantiate(columnPrefab, objectPoolPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            }
    }
```

becomes

```
private GameObject[] instantiatedColumns;
public GameObject[] columnPrefabs;
void Start()
    {
        instantiatedColumns= new GameObject[columnPrefabs.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < columnPrefabs.Length; i++)
            {
                instantiatedColumns[i] = Instantiate(columnPrefabs[i], objectPoolPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            }
    }
```

This way you will instantiate each prefab in prefab columns array (populated in the inspector) and save references into a new array "instantiatedColumns", then you may use this array in Update()

Comment: instantiateColumns[currentColumn].transform.position = new Vector2(spawnXPosition,spawnYPosition);
            
           


            
        

    } this line gives an error. But this time it gives an error "IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
ColumbPool.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/ColumbPool.cs:55)" Anyway thanks for your help.. it does show the 4 different prefabs but it does not instantiate it.